# DB2 : Optimization required for a query

Tags: view, db2

I have to fetch data from DB2 database from a .NET in following way:

1. join 5 tables 2 inner join 3 left outer join
2. the data have to be written on a text file . so functions such as LPAD/RPAD, substr etc for formatting have to be used.
3. the data retrieved would be about 100000 rows

I am planning to create a view so that application gets rid of joins and i get required columns only in the view.
I want to know If formatting of data should also be moved to the definition of view? So that in the application I will perform only

> select * from view

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is really no difference from the database engine's perspective whether the application submits a query with joins, text functions, etc or if all of these are contained within a view and the application executes a simple `select * from view`.  DB2 compiles the query in exactly the same way.

The only "advantage" to using a view is convenience for the application developer.  The disadvantage to putting the SQL statement into a view, of course, is that if the requirements change you'll have to modify the view.

As far as including the text formatting within the view:  If this view will exist ONLY to support this one single application (and you're using it only for convenience), then it may make sense to include the formatting within the view definition.  However, if other applications may have some need for the view (but not the text formatting), then keeping the formatting in your query against the view is the better choice.

As a DBA, I would suggest that the *best* place for text formatting is within your application code.  Writing a formatted string using `printf()` (or equivalent) is something that applications are usually pretty good at.

Comment: thanks for the insight. Could you please suggest how can I optimize the fetching of data in this case. I cannot make changes to existing db tables.What features of .NET can help in this regard?